# How to exclude frameworks in simulator builds in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios, compilation

How can I exclude libraries which I have compiled only for the iOS device architecture (libssh2, etc.) from an Xcode project when I am compiling the app to run on the simulator?

Comment: why not compiling them also for i386 and create a universal "binary" with "lipo"? Then you can also test libss2, etc. on simulator. Do you need help on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but if someone's still looking for the answer, you can use **Weak Linking** to specify that certain libraries are *optional*.

See [this answer for how to define a weak/optional link in XCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6480788/119114)

Then, in the code that would normally use the features, you can detect that you're in the simulator at compile time with

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

  NSLog(@"I'm in the simulator");

#endif
```

or at run time by inspecting the value of

```
  [[UIDevice currentDevice] model]
```

and programmatically avoid using the libraries that don't exist in the simulator environment.

Comment: Why ideas how to NOT embed both frameworks into the ipa?