# Objective-C: How to check if a C function is supported

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, respondstoselector

How can I perform a run-time check to see if I can use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, which is only available starting with iOS 4.

I know I could check `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]`, but Apple recommends using things like `NSClassFromString()` or `respondsToSelector:`. Is there a `respondsToSelector:` for C functions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's another option, which I've been using.

C functions are pointers.  If you "weak" link to `UIKit` framework, on iOS 3 the function pointer will simply be `NULL`, so you can test for the existence of the function by doing:

```
if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
{
    // On iOS 4+, use the main screen's native scale factor (for iPhone 4).
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
}
else
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
}
```

See also: [How do I weak link frameworks on Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480765/how-do-i-weak-link-frameworks-on-xcode-4)

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably interested in here is [weak linking](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW6). (See "Listing 3-2: Checking the availability of a C function".)

Answer (score -2):

This is what I'm going with:

```
if ([mainScreen respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
} else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
}
```

I think this is good enough, but if you have any better suggestions, please answer.

Comment: That scale call exists on iOS 3.2, which had a "scale" method that was not documented... so "respondsToSelector" will work, but the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions call is only available from iOS 4.0 onward.  Thus it would crash on the original non-upgraded iPad.  I would use Daniels check, you should always check for the exact call you are about to make and not rely on "pairings" of call checking like this.