# Can I use a constant declared in a framework without linking against the framework?

Tags: objective-c, frameworks

I want to access a constant NSString that is defined in a framework in objective-c without statically linking to the framework.  I'm working on a framework myself and I don't want to link against the other framework because I know that some clients of my framework won't support the new framework.  I've found that I can dynamically load a framework using NSBundle and that I can dynamically create instances of the class by using NSClassFromString, but the compiler (actually I guess it's the linker) won't let me use constants because they are undefined symbols.

Edit:
I have a suspicion that my answer is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html

I found the answer here: [How do I weak link frameworks on Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480765/how-do-i-weak-link-frameworks-on-xcode-4)

What happens then if I try and access something from the framework?  Do I just get nil?