# Error in facebook integration in ios6?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

I working on facebook integration in ios6.I added social,accounts frameworks and import as follows

```
#import "social /Social.h"
#import "accounts /Accounts.h"
```

but i got "social /Social.h not found" error.Any idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could be the blank space before /Social.h ? :-)

Comment: make capital letter as initial.. Social /Social.h and Accounts /Accounts.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
#import <Social/Social.h>
```

Comment: if you want to make your app iOS 5 compatible, make sure to set the Social,Accounts,AddSupport framework as Optional from the build phases. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6480788/857865

Answer (score 0):

Make capital letter as initial when importing iOS frameworks.

Just like this.

```
#import "Social/Social.h"
#import "Accounts/Accounts.h"
```

Comment: try simply like this. import "Social.h"