# Weak Linked Framework Causing "File Not Found" Error

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, frameworks, weak-linking

I am building an app that uses the `Social.h` and `Accounts.h` frameworks.

I have both Frameworks set as `optional`. 
I have my `Base SDK` set as `6.0`
I have `iOS Deployment Target` set as `5.0`

When I build the app to my iPhone running `6.0`, everything works fine. When I build to my iPhone Simulator running `5.0`, I get errors that saying `Social/Social.h file not found` (I do not get this error for Accounts.h, which seems odd. I would think it would be all or nothing.)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. Is it possible there is simply something awry with your Frameworks path? Or something else relating to where Xcode is trying to find these files? Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: In the project navigator, do you have an absolute path to any of these frameworks? How were they added to the project? Accounts framework exists in the iOS 5 SDK, but Social does not. That is probably part of the problem. The paths on both should show "Relative to SDK".

Comment: This might be my problem. I can't look at it right now but will report back asap.

Comment: This is set to "Relative to SDK" - does it matter what's in my Build Settings under "Framework Search Paths" ?

Comment: Try installing/re-installing the latest XCode.

Comment: In your project first delete both framework . Added again both framework in your project and set optional .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your suggestions.

In the end it was a problem with my iOS Simulator. I am assuming if I go through the whole re-install, it will solve my problem. I was able to get my hands on an actual device that is running iOS 5.0 and it ran as expected. The problem only occurs when I run it on my simulator.

Answer (score 0):

[Error in facebook integration in ios6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145571/error-in-facebook-integration-in-ios6)
strong text
Try this

```
**#import <Social/Social.h>**
```