# What is the difference between adding a dylib to "Link Binary With Libraries" and adding to "Other Linker Flags"

Tags: ios, xcode

In my case, I'm adding "libsqlite3.dylib" to "Link Binary With Libraries" in the "Build Phases" of my iOS XCode project. I was told that this can potentially cause rejection during app submittal and that I should add "-libsqlite3" to "Other Linker Flags" in "Build Settings" instead. What is the ideal approach?

Comment: I find it quite bizarre that one could be rejected while the other one is safe. Dynamic libraries are not allowed in XCode and Apple doesn't permit them due to safety concerns. A .dylib extension, however, doesn't mean the library is linked dynamically. By either way, you are linking the library statically and it should be just fine.

Comment: And the answer by @lancegoh refers to the difference between optional and required frameworks. By marking it optional, you allow users without that library to still be able to download your app. However, you have to manually check for library presence in the code otherwise it would crash the second that library is referenced. And libsqlite3 has been around for a while now, (even deprecated by Core Data) so I don't see why you would have to mark it optional (assuming lancegoh is right)

Answer (score 0):

Just linking this back to another post on Weak link

[How do I weak link frameworks on Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480765/how-do-i-weak-link-frameworks-on-xcode-4)

You may want to visit apple's documentation on the differences.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html