# How do I detect, at runtime, that a framework has been loaded?

Tags: ios, frameworks, runtime, static-libraries

I'm building a static library to distribute to other folks to use in iOS apps, wherein I'd like to take advantage of of frameworks *only if they have been included in the app* by the users of my library. I've figured out how to compile the library so that it does not itself include any frameworks, but as soon as I try to use it in an app, it fails, because the library references frameworks that don't exist.

I'd rather not force my clients to load frameworks they don't need. [Weak-linking frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480765/how-do-i-weak-link-frameworks-on-xcode-4) is cool, but that just means that the framework doesn't have to be present on the system (e.g., for older versions of iOS); its support is still compiled into the binary. Better would be not to require the framework to be linked *at all*, and only use it if it is linked (optionally or not).

So, is there any way to detect that a framework is included in an iOS app at runtime, not just whether it's present on the system?

Comment: `NSClassFromString(@"FrameworkClass") == nil`

Comment: No, that just tells me if the framework is present on the system, not whether the app included it.

Comment: what are the differences?

Comment: In your version, you test if the class in question is present on the device. What I want to do is detect whether the user of my app has required the framework that includes that class.

Comment: so you want to know does the app developer include a framework explicitly? not sure how useful is that... you can ask them to `#define USE_SOME_FRAMEWORK`

Comment: Yeah, I can add methods to the interface to turn things on and off, but would rather save my clients the additional complexity. I guess my real question is, what does it mean to say that a framework is linked? If a framework is not linked, are the classes not available?

Comment: @BryanChen did some testing with `NSClassFromString()`, turns out you're exactly right, it's just what I needed! Happy to accept your answer if you add one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"FrameworkClass") == nil) {
   // the framework is not available
} else {
   // the framework is avaiable
}
```

Comment: Works great, as long as you're careful to instantiate objects with the class returned by `NSClassFromString()`.

Comment: @theory & Bryan-Chen: could you provide insight how you achieved this? I'm creating a lib too that would provide additional funcs if Firebase is linked with the host project. But this is the error I get http://imgur.com/a/bRgQ3

Comment: @akdsouza You either have to include the relevant headers and then test to see if the class is loaded at runtime via `NSClassFromString()` or make `baseRef` have the type `id`.

Comment: @theory I ended up doing just that and using reflection; else the compiler would throw errors.