# Dynamically link binaries with library in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

To link binaries to you framework you can from build phase add your needed libraries to your project .. but what if I need to make some thing specific for example I need to customise my framework by adding or deleting binaries.. foe example I want lite version and full version so I need always to delete and add these binaries from "**Link binary..**" tab
Is there any dynamic way like to make different configuration files or some thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to create 2 Xcode targets, one for *lite* and one for *pro*, which compile the same source files and link to mostly the same frameworks etc.

You can also add compiler constants to the *Build Settings* of these targets, which will allow the common source files to behave differently between these target "products".

Comment: Thanks for your reply ..I will try your solution..
I was thinking how the life will be good if I can create a new distribution that will link my libraries with it..
what do you think of this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443656/conditional-link-static-library-in-xcode-with-environment-variable?rq=1

Comment: @MohanadKaleia I think my idea of using 2 build targets is better.  It's easier to manage, more flexible and fully supported by the Xcode UI, not just the command line tool.

Comment: thanks a lot .. your solution is really good I will go with it .. best regards