# define variable for compiler in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

Whin I setting "Other Linker Flags" in Xcode, I have to put absolute path for .a file (/Users/AAA/.local/lib/libfoo.a).

Could I define a variable like $LIBPREFIX=/User/AAA/.local/lib and set the "Other Linker Flags" to $LIBPREFIX/libfoo.a

Comment: [Why not just link it like this....](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/configuration.html) (same concept on OS X or iOS). Why the need for a variable?

Comment: I have many static libs and I need to give project to my partner, his directory is not the same, variable just need one change

Comment: If not including the libraries in the project [this answer might be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19132075/499581).